# Is throwing other PC's possible?

Tags: dnd-4e, combat, opportunity-attack, encounters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you rule halfling tossing as a combat action?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/6623/how-do-you-rule-halfling-tossing-as-a-combat-action)

Hello, one of my fellow players brought upon a good question to me; is possible to throw another PC almost like a projectile? The PC is a Goliath Barbarian and has some massive strength and she wants to throw a little 80 lb Halfling Rogue in order to add little spice too an encounter. I had no idea to that so let me ask you guys, could it be possible?thanks  :)

Comment: Have you looked at this question yet? http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/6623/how-do-you-rule-halfling-tossing-as-a-combat-action

Comment: Yes, but remember, nobody tosses a dwarf!  (sorry, sorry)

Answer (score 0):

So long as the strength attribute is enough to lift the PC, it's possible (lift over head). If it's close, they would be able to throw them far though. If the PC only weighs 50% of the characters lift, then I'd allow something like a 5 ft throw.

Also, it depends whether the PC being thrown is struggling against being thrown - for this I'd add a skills check. :)